# What is considered bad markup?

Tags: html

I want to ready myself for future front end dev interviews, and this [site](https://moz.com/blog/interviewing-web-developers-20-good-questions-to-ask) said the below:

> If they write something like: `<image src="/some/image.gif">`, it
>   might be a good hint to wrap things up and call the next interviewee.

What is wrong with that markup?

Comment: Read [**this**](https://github.com/bendc/frontend-guidelines) and [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/4305494).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `<image>`, it should be `<img>`.

**Edit:** A promising front end dev stays up to date with the capabilities of the browsers and their versions, so that the markup is able to present what it was intended to. For example, the post you linked was dated 2006 (a lot of new capabilities introduced with HTML5). We would have to consider these details, especially from the user-browser side. Good luck for the interviews!

Answer (score 1):

Good markup is [semantically correct](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html-5-semantics/). That's it.

Try to avoid using inline styles as well.

also `image` should be `img`.